# Is Bitcoin mining profitable in india?

Tags: mining-hardware

I am looking to buy a Bitcoin miner. I am from india. So I want to ask , will it be profitable to buy a bitcoin miner set and start a mining business in India ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all depends on your local electricity costs, including cooling costs.  It may also be determined by the rates offered at the exchanges you have access to.

I don't know of any India-specific mining profitability calculators, but [here's one](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/bitcoin-mining-calculator) that calculates based on US dollars.  You could probably convert your costs to dollars and come up with a reasonable answer.

Comment: Warning: be careful with calculators: I've come across at least one that does not take the halvening into account. It simply keeps using 25BTC per block. I haven't tried the one mentioned here, so this is just a general warning.

Comment: I think , you are absolutely right.  Because , the cost of electricity is really expensive in india. And a individual miner can't make much profit using high rate electricity.